# Google reCaptcha integrating with LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a LWC Site Page, which has Input field Email Address and Submit button, Once submitted we will send an form Link to the Provided Email Address.

To avoid junk data , I'm implementing the captcha in my site. For that I gone through several link and tried to implement, I'm getting empty CAptcha like below

[image]

```
 <iframe src={_url} id="recaptchaIframe" scrolling="no" style={_height}></iframe>
```

```
@track navigateTo="/apex/portalSmartyAddress";
    @track _url="";
    @track _height="";
    @track data;
    
    @api
    get height() {
        return this._height;
    }

    set height(value) {
       this._height = value;
    }

    @api
    get url() {
        return this._url;
    }

    set url(value) {
       this._url = value;
    }

    @api
    getAddress() {
        return window.address;
    }
    
    @api
    getValue()
    {
       return window.data;
    }
    
    listenMessage(msg) 
    {
        window.data=msg.data;
        this.data=msg.data;
        if(this.data!=='Unlock')
        {
            window.address=msg.data
        }
    }
    connectedCallback()
    {
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.addEventListener("message", this.listenMessage, false);
        } else {
            window.attachEvent("onmessage", this.listenMessage);
        }
    }
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
          var verifyCallback = function(response) {
              parent.postMessage("Unlock", "{!$Site.BaseSecureUrl}");
          };
          var onloadCallback = function() {
              grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
                  'sitekey' :'6Ld4EJsUAAAAABqSFVI2i8f7VZdRQJ1g0zOsJSQx',
                  'callback' : verifyCallback,
              });
          };
        </script>

 <form action="?" method="POST">
          <div id="html_element"></div>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="display:none"/>
        </form>
        <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async="" defer="">
        </script>
```

Comment: Did you check the browser console for any errors?

Comment: Checked No error in Console